# Wrong data types when reading data with spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

if I try to specify the schema when reading a file using pyspark, the read method doesn't fail when the schema is incorrect. For example:

```
schema = '''
{
"fields":
[
{"metadata":{},"name":"id0","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"id1","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"name","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"timestamp","nullable":true,"type":"string"}
],"type":"struct"}
'''
schemaFromJson = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schema))

df2 = spark.read.format("csv") \
      .option("header", True) \
      .schema(schemaFromJson) \
      .load(s3InputPath)
```

yields

```
+----+----+----+---------+
| id0| id1|name|timestamp|
+----+----+----+---------+
|null|null|null|     null|
|null|null|null|     null|
|null|null|null|     null|
|null|null|null|     null|
+----+----+----+---------+
```

because the "name" field is a string and I told it to read as integer.
Is there any way of making the read method fail in such cases?

Data sample:

```
id0,id1,name,timestamp
10,1,Name1,01/03/2021 13:00
10,2,Name2,01/03/2021 13:00
10,3,Name3,01/03/2021 13:00
10,4,Name4,01/03/2021 13:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a small data sample?

Comment: any data will do. 
I added some to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `mode=PERMISSIVE|FAILFAST|DROPMALFORMED`:

**Scenario 1:** Store unprocessed data into another column:

```py
schema = '''
{
"fields":
[
{"metadata":{},"name":"id0","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"id1","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"name","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"timestamp","nullable":true,"type":"string"},
{"metadata":{},"name":"_corrupt_record","nullable":true,"type":"string"}
],"type":"struct"}
'''
schemaFromJson = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schema))

df2 = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", True) \
    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record") \
    .schema(schemaFromJson) \
    .load(s3InputPath, mode='PERMISSIVE')
df2.show()
```

```
Output:
+---+---+--------+----------------+--------------------+
|id0|id1|    name|       timestamp|     _corrupt_record|
+---+---+--------+----------------+--------------------+
| 10|  1|    null|01/03/2021 13:00|10,1,Name1,01/03/...|
| 10|  2|    null|01/03/2021 13:00|10,2,Name2,01/03/...|
| 10|  3|    null|01/03/2021 13:00|10,3,Name3,01/03/...|
| 10|  4|    null|01/03/2021 13:00|10,4,Name4,01/03/...|
| 10|  5|40028922|01/03/2021 13:00|                null|
+---+---+--------+----------------+--------------------+
```

**Scenario 2:** Raise an exception

```py
df2 = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", True) \
    .schema(schemaFromJson) \
    .load(s3InputPath, mode='FAILFAST')
```

```
Output:
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.BadRecordException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Name1"
[...]
```

**Scenario 3:** Handle only valid data

```py
df2 = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", True) \
    .schema(schemaFromJson) \
    .load(s3InputPath, mode='DROPMALFORMED')
df2.show()
```

```
Output:
+---+---+--------+----------------+
|id0|id1|    name|       timestamp|
+---+---+--------+----------------+
| 10|  5|40028922|01/03/2021 13:00|
+---+---+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: this is excellent, thanks very much for your answer. I wish I could accept it 100 times :)
two follow up comments. Due to the lazy load nature of spark (I believe) the error on scenario 2 only occurs on the show() command. Any idea on how to make it happen on the read? (other than maybe issue a show() right after it).
Second question: on scenario3, is there a way of knowing how many rows were dropped? thanks again

Comment: Question 1: as you said, it's a lazy load. Under the hoods the exception will be raised when spark starts to read your file, but this will be only triggered after an action call (show, count, collect, write, etc.). Question 2: The easier way is using `mode=PERMISSIVE` and applying a `.where` condition to filter all rows where _corrupt_record is not null. From what I know, `DROPMALFORMED` option doesn't store any metadata about how many records were dropped